# Use PHP method from different class/file

Tags: php, oop

If I want to add methods to my file from other classes or a script not using OOP should I include() the file or extend it in my class?

Answer (score 2):

Include and create a new instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

For OOP classes you would have to decide if the object needs to be an instance. If its just a utility of functions you could use static methods like below:

```
class EmailFilter
{

     public function clean($email) 
     {
         ...
     }

     public static function filter($email) {
         ....
     }
}
```

You would then require the code and use

**Static**

```
EmailFilter::filter($email);
```

**Object**

```
$filter = new EmailFilter();

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $filter->clean($email);
}
```

if its non-oop functions you can include/require the code and use the functions as needed within your code.